# PCA Implementation in Java

Tags: java, pca

I need implementation of PCA in Java. I am interested in finding something that's well documented, practical and easy to use. Any recommendations?

Comment: Why is this question off-topic ? A comment could at least to explain this choice.
Because I found that question interesting like 22 people who upvoted it and it's answer.

Answer (score 18):

There are now a number of Principal Component Analysis implementations for Java.

1. Apache Spark: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html#principal-component-analysis-pca

   ```
   SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("PCAExample").setMaster("local");
   try (JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf)) {
       //Create points as Spark Vectors
       List<Vector> vectors = Arrays.asList(
               Vectors.dense( -1.0, -1.0 ),
               Vectors.dense( -1.0, 1.0 ),
               Vectors.dense( 1.0, 1.0 ));

       //Create Spark MLLib RDD
       JavaRDD<Vector> distData = sc.parallelize(vectors);
       RDD<Vector> vectorRDD = distData.rdd();

       //Execute PCA Projection to 2 dimensions
       PCA pca = new PCA(2); 
       PCAModel pcaModel = pca.fit(vectorRDD);
       Matrix matrix = pcaModel.pc();
   }
   ```
2. ND4J: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.nd4j/nd4j-api/latest/org/nd4j/linalg/dimensionalityreduction/PCA.html

   ```
   //Create points as NDArray instances
   List<INDArray> ndArrays = Arrays.asList(
           new NDArray(new float [] {-1.0F, -1.0F}),
           new NDArray(new float [] {-1.0F, 1.0F}),
           new NDArray(new float [] {1.0F, 1.0F}));

   //Create matrix of points (rows are observations; columns are features)
   INDArray matrix = new NDArray(ndArrays, new int [] {3,2});

   //Execute PCA - again to 2 dimensions
   INDArray factors = PCA.pca_factor(matrix, 2, false);
   ```
3. Apache Commons Math (single threaded; no framework)

   ```
   //create points in a double array
   double[][] pointsArray = new double[][] { 
       new double[] { -1.0, -1.0 }, 
       new double[] { -1.0, 1.0 },
       new double[] { 1.0, 1.0 } };

   //create real matrix
   RealMatrix realMatrix = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(pointsArray);

   //create covariance matrix of points, then find eigenvectors
   //see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues

   Covariance covariance = new Covariance(realMatrix);
   RealMatrix covarianceMatrix = covariance.getCovarianceMatrix();
   EigenDecomposition ed = new EigenDecomposition(covarianceMatrix);
   ```

Note, Singular Value Decomposition, which can also be used to find Principal Components, has equivalent implementations.

Comment: Remember to mean-center your data before PCA.  Notice LotiLotiLoti did this implicitly in the example.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one: [PCA Class](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/PCA.html).

> This class contains the methods necessary for a basic Principal Component Analysis with a varimax rotation. Options are available for an analysis using either the covariance or the correlation martix. A parallel analysis, using Monte Carlo simulations, is performed. Extraction criteria based on eigenvalues greater than unity, greater than a Monte Carlo eigenvalue percentile or greater than the Monte Carlo eigenvalue means are available.

Answer (score 2):

check http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/attributeSelection/PrincipalComponents.html
weka in fact have many other algorithm that could be used with along with PCA and also weka is adding more algorithm from time to time. so i thing, if you are working on java then switch to weka api.

Comment: Invalid link, please try to avoid answering questions with only a link, as they can expire and be unreliable in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[Smile](http://haifengl.github.io/smile/) is a full-fledged ML library for java. You give its PCA implementation a try. Please see: https://haifengl.github.io/smile/api/java/smile/projection/PCA.html

There is also PCA [tutorial](http://xyclade.github.io/MachineLearning/#using-unsupervised-learning-to-merge-features-pca) with Smile but the tutorial uses Scala.

Comment: It's Apache 2.0 licensed.  It appears to auto-center the data. And provides for projections. And switches to a SVD implementation when appropriate & permitted.  https://haifengl.github.io/smile/feature.html#dimension-reduction

Answer (score 1):

You can see a few implementations of PCA in the DataMelt project:

https://jwork.org/dmelt/code/index.php?keyword=PCA

(they are rewritten in Jython). They include some graphical examples for dimensionality reduction. They show the usage of several Java packages, such as JSAT, DatumBox and others.